# Errors Clipping a Vector: Invalid Geometry

Tags: clip

I have a vector that was polygonized from a raster. I'm hoping to clip it within the boundaries of a certain shapefile "noFertZone" (the turquoise box). In the end I want a "noPKS" shapefile that only encompasses everything within the turquoise box.

[image]

However, when I use the clip by mask tool It only clips the elements fully within the turquoise box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8tze.png)

[image]

When I do the simple clip tool, like I would in ArcGIS, my input looks like this. However, the clip tool is spitting back an 'invalid geometry' error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried every clipping option I could think of.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not clear how to answer your question, if there is an unacceptable geometry at the borders of turquoise color, then it needs to be corrected, and I don’t understand why you cut not with a polygon, but with a border ...

Comment: That "border" is a polygon, it's just not filled in. I just did this exact process in ArcGIS using the clip tool and it worked perfectly.

Comment: well, I realized, in this case, you need to correct the geometry ... the coordinates of the location of the error you have, go to edit mode (pencil) and delete the wrong point (or points) ...